Notion of Determinant for a 4-rank tensor
I'm having some difficulties with the concept of the determinant for a rank-4 real tensor in d=4.
I have found in the literature that Cayley generalized the notion of determinant for a rank-3 matrix in d=2. Moreover, I have read that mathematicians have studied the concepts of combinatorial and geometrical hyperdeterminants, where the notion of tensors can be connected to another type of object known as hypermatrices.
I work in physics, and I would greatly appreciate guidance on the correct interpretation of these concepts, as well as references to begin exploring this topic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant

$\def\Ts{\mathcal{T}^1_1}$A tensor $T \in V \otimes V \otimes V^* \otimes V^$ can be viewed as an endomorphism $\beta_T:V \otimes V^ \to V \otimes V^$. Since $\Ts\equiv V \otimes V^$ is a vector space you can define a $k$-form on this vector space (a totally anti-symmetric multilinear map $\underbrace{\Ts \times \cdots \times \Ts}_\text{$k$ times} \to R$); if $k = {\rm dim }, \Ts$  then you have a top form $\omega$. Given a basis $E^j_i$ of $\Ts$ you can define the "determinant" of $T$ as $$\det T :=\frac{\omega(\beta_T(E^1_1),\ldots,\beta_T(E^n_n))}{\omega(E^1_1,\ldots,E^n_n)}.$$
